# Elmish App: Change <body> style dynamically

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish

Version

```
    nuget Fable.Core ~> 3
    nuget Fable.Elmish ~> 3
```

How to change body style in elmish app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Dom through the `Fable.Import.Browser` module.

Try e.g.,

```
open Fable.Import

Browser.document.body.style.fontSize <- "20px"
```

or

```
Browser.document.body.classList.add("my-class")
Browser.document.body.classList.remove("my-class")
```

Comment: In version 1.3.0, It seems to be `Browser.Dom.document` instead of `Browser.document`. Anyway, it works! Thank you for your answer.